# Count Number of Associated Products Assigned to a Configurable Product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, associated-products

Is it possible to get a count of the total number of associated products assigned to a configurable product?

I have tried using the following functions:

- `getConfigurableAttributesAsArray()`
- `getProductCount()`
- `count()`

However, I've only seen this working when applied to categories, not configurable products. While I do want to output the count in `list.phtml`, I want to output it per product, not for the entire category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the approach offered by [jigs parmar](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/43952/jigs-parmar) does work, it is a HUGE performance hit if used in a loop! A much better approach is:

```
$childIds = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getChildrenIds($_product->getId(), false); //$_product is defined in the loop
$colors = count($childIds[0]); //getChildrenIds() returns an encapsulated array
echo $colors.' Color';
if ($colors != 1) echo 's'; //make "Color" plural
```

The reason is that `getUsedProducts()` returns every simple product along with every attribute of those products. In a loop, that took forever!

Since I only needed the number of products, I could use `getChildrenIds()` which only returns the ID of the simple products--much lighter code!

Comment: I'm still looking to improve this code so that it doesn't include disabled products.

Comment: This works for Magento 2 also

Comment: @Ajith, who said it didn't ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$product_confi = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('1100'); //configure product id
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product_confi);

echo count($childProducts);
```

it will print total associate product associate with configure product.

if you want to get only enabled product than use this code

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(418); 
                    $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                                    ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);
$count=0;   
foreach($childProducts as $child) 
{
    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child->getId());
        echo $product->getId(). '-'.$product->getStatus();
        if($product->getStatus()==1)
        {
            $count++;
        }
        echo '<br>';
}

echo 'total enable product is '.$count;


?>
```

Comment: This is working great, thanks! Is there any performance hit by loading `product_type_configurable`?

Comment: no. its only to load child product

Comment: This is working good, except for the fact that it still counts associated products that have been disabled. How can we narrow it down to only enabled associated products?

Comment: you use foreach loop for this. and check that product is enable or not

Comment: I did loop through the array to check the status. However, the count is unchanged by disabled products. It seems the issue comes from passing "null" as the first parameter of `getUsedProducts`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6584928/3254362 

I tried adding the code as shown here with no luck: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/68807/24331

Comment: plz post your code

Comment: <?php if ($_product->isConfigurable()) {
     $entityId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('catalog_product');
     $attribute_id = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode($entityId, 'status');
                          $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(array($attribute_id),$_product);
      $count = 0;
     foreach ($childProducts as $child) {
       if ($child->getStatus()) $count++;
     }
                          echo ' ('.$count.' Colors Available)';
    } ?>

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: do you see any issues with the code?

Comment: wait i'l check this

Comment: did you find any possible code updates?

Comment: can you tell me what youe requirment is? ?

Comment: Just trying to remove inactive products from the count.

Comment: i edit my code you check. it will count product which is enable

Comment: did you check my code?

Comment: I will check it soon.

Comment: i check it. and it will work fine thats why im telling you to check . and if it fullfill your requirment than accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for Tier price condition in magento and it's working fine showing price on simple products count in configurable product.

```
<?php                               
                                $childIds = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getChildrenIds($_product->getId(), false); //$_product is defined in the loop
                                $colors = count($childIds[0]); //getChildrenIds() returns an encapsulated array
                                if ($colors == 2) {                                 
                                    echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
                                } else { ?>                                     
                                    <span class="price-label" style="color:#03c069; margin-bottom:0px; display:none;"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></span>
                                    <span class="price" style="color:#113b80; margin-top: 6px;"> <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency (Min($allTier), true, true); ?> </span>
                            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: This is pretty much the same as my selected answer except you are using it to output price (not what I need) instead of the count. The only problem with my (and your) code is that disabled products are included in the count. I need a way so that the disabled products aren't included.